# Remove the white background-color from the fancybox-inner div

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there a way to remove the white background-color from the fancybox-inner div?

heres what i was trying..

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({padding : 0, background: 'none'});
```

Comment: which version of fancybox you are using ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change it via an inline `CSS` declaration.

After you linked to the fancybox *css* file add this:

```
   .fancybox-skin {
      background-color: #ff0000; /* or whatever */
    }
```

The default values for that selector are:

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #444444;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

eventually, you can change the `background-color` within your script using the `beforeShow` callback option like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 beforeShow: function(){
  $(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor","transparent");
 }
});
```

**NOTICE** that I used `transparent` if you want to *remove* it (`none` is not a valid value in this case)

Answer (score 3):

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#helpers

In Version 2 there is a way through the helpers:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers:  {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#fff'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but that won't change the color of the inner `DIV` where the fancybox content is displayed but the background behind of it.

Comment: I wonder if this css helper can be used to add `border-radius` to the shadowed title box when set to over with `title : { type : 'over' }`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an additional class to the fancybox-inner div like:

```
class="white"
```

And then just set it there:

```
background: #FFF;
```

And it will override the default.

Comment: the question was for "a way to remove"

Comment: Add in none; or anything else you prefer =]